# UTF-8 characters not displayed with xelatex (pandoc)

Tags: fonts, unicode, characters

I'm using XeLaTeX with `pandoc` to generate PDFs from markdown files: but the "⇒" character (UTF8) does not get correctly generated (it's not show in the output file). Is it possible to get the "⇒" character converted from markdown to PDF without using `$\Rightarrow$`?

(I'm already using the `xunicode` and `xlxstra` packages)

Comment: Pandoc converts the file correctly. The point is that the text font you use (probably latin modern) does not contain the ⇒ character. If you change the font to e.g. iwona, the ⇒ symbol appears.

Comment: @Marco: Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 8):

Pandoc converts the file correctly. If you open the resulting file with a text
editor you see the ⇒ symbol, which in turn means that pandoc has done a good
job.

The point is that the text font you use (probably Latin Modern) does not
contain the ⇒ character. If you change the font to a different one which
contains the ⇒ symbol, e.g. iwona, it will appear as expected.

If you want to keep using Latin Modern as bodyfont, here's a small hack which
takes the ⇒ symbol from the math font instead (it's a plain TeX solution, maybe LaTeX provides some nice abstraction around this): Place the
following code into `fixRightarrow.tex`:

```
\catcode`\⇒\active
\def⇒{$\Rightarrow$}
```

and call pandoc with the `--include-before-body` argument:

```
pandoc \
  --include-before-body=fixRightarrow.tex \
  --to=latex                              \
  --output=output.tex                     \
  input.md
```